# @ngrx/store update from v10 to v11 / v12

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx-store

Good day.

I need help with the following issue. A while back we updated our project to use Angular 12 and I have been trying to update @ngrx/store from v10 to v11 (or v12). I did try this update when we were still using Angular 11 as well, but I keep getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'ReducerTypes<unknown, [ActionCreator<"EnableForm", () => TypedAction<"EnableForm">>]>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ReducerTypes<AppState, ActionCreator<string, Creator<any[], object>>[]>'.
  Types of property 'reducer' are incompatible.
    Type 'OnReducer<unknown, [ActionCreator<"EnableForm", () => TypedAction<"EnableForm">>]>' is not assignable to type 'OnReducer<AppState, ActionCreator<string, Creator<any[], object>>[]>'.
      Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'AppState'.
```

My reducer looks something like this:

```js
import { Action, createReducer, on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as MyAction from '../actions';
import { AppState } from '../state';
import { onEnableForm, onDisableForm } from './form.reducer';

const initialState: AppState = {
    form: {
         disabled: false,
         ...
    },
    ...
};
export function storeReducer(state: AppState = initialState, action: Action): AppState {
    return createReducer<AppState>(
        state,
        on(MyAction.InitializeState, MyAction.ResetState, () => initialState),
        on(MyAction.DestroyState, () => undefined),
        onEnableForm,
        onDisableForm
    )(state, action);
}
```

`actions.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { createAction } from '@ngrx/store';

export const InitializeState = createAction('[MyFeatureStore] InitializeState');

export const ResetState = createAction('[MyFeatureStore] ResetState');

export const DestroyState = createAction('[MyFeatureStore] DestroyState');

export const EnableForm = createAction('[MyFeatureStore] EnableForm');

export const DisableForm = createAction('[MyFeatureStore] DisableForm');
```

And `form.reducer.ts` looks like this:

```js
import { on } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as MyAction from '../actions';
import { AppState } from '../state';

export const onEnableForm = on(MyAction.EnableForm, (state: AppState) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        form: {
            ...state.form,
            disabled: false
        }
    };
});
export const onDisableForm = on(MyAction.DisableForm, (state: AppState) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        form: {
            ...state.form,
            disabled: true
        }
    };
});
```

This works okay in v10, but I can't figure out why it's not working in v11.

Comment: Can you provide the function for `MyAction.EnableForm` and `MyAction.DisableForm`

Comment: I'm using the `createAction` function from `@ngrx/store`. I've included it in the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing that is happening is that angular and all of the typescript world are moving to more and more strongly typed rules, so when you are creating the `on` function outside the pipe, typescript cant infer what's going on.

The thing that you can do is to extend the types of your `on` functions like so

```js
export const onEnableForm = on<AppState, any>(EnableForm, (state: AppState): AppState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    form: {
      ...state.form,
      disabled: false,
    }
  };
});
export const onDisableForm = on<AppState, any>(
  DisableForm,
  (state: AppState): AppState => {
    return {
      ...state,
      form: {
        ...state.form,
        disabled: true
      }
    };
  }
);
```

You can use it as a workaround until you find the appropriate types to use instead of the `any`. Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-prupaa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fstore.ts) with the proposed solution.

Comment: This has been helpful, thank you. I've found that instead of `any`, this also works: 
`export const onEnableForm = on<AppState, typeof EnableForm[]>(EnableForm, (state: AppState, whateverProps) => { ... }`